# .bashrc includes valid NDK and SDK paths - however Ubuntu still displays 'Could not find ndk-build. and 'Could not find android'

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk, makefile

I'm attempting to 'make' a project in Ubuntu and my .bashrc (in my home directory)  includes valid NDK and SDK paths:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/user/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/user/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/user/Downloads/android-ndk-r10e
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/Downloads/android-sdk-linux
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true
```

...however Ubuntu still displays `'Could not find ndk-build. Please install Android NDK' and Could not find android. Please install android SDK`

Anyone know how this might be resolved? Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your PATH variable have this modification ? try `echo $PATH` to check it. if not run `source .bashrc` or restart your shell. If your PATH variable is correct, i do not know what is wrong ...

Comment: One of the reasons it could happen is that .bashrc is executed for interactive non-login shells (see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoked-as-an-interactive-non_002dlogin-shell for details). Solution is, as aforementioned URL says, to call .bashrc from your .profile/.bash_profile script.